# How do I give myself admin rights to a sql server instance, having forgotten the sa password?

Tags: passwords, sql-server, administration

I have lost all `passwords` for a SQL Server instance, how do I give myself admin access again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run SSMS as Administrator (ie, with escalated privileges on the server). This should have sysadmin rights, and you can then find your login and assign rights as necessary.

Almost wrote "tights" there. You can probably assign them too, if you're running as an admin on the server.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Configuration Manager
2. Stop the server instance
3. Right, click >> properties >> advanced >> startup parameters
4. Add "-m;" right at the start of the
   string ensuring there are no spaces
   anywhere in the string
5. Restart server
6. `sqlcmd -S localhost` from the
   command prompt
7. `EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember
   'domain\username', 'sysadmin'; GO`
8. `exit`
9. Ensure can connect from command
   prompt `sqlcmd -S localhost -E` (if logged-in as that user to windows)
10. Remove "-m;" from startup parameters
11. Restart the database server

Comment: And with screenshots! http://blogs.ameriteach.com/chris-randall/2009/12/11/sql-server-2008-forgot-to-add-an-administrator-account.html

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me: step 9 was unable to connect. But note that at step 6 you can instead run SSMS locally and create the login that way. That worked for me.